# Setting spinner value in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-spinner

I have a spinner which takes 3 values `("Birth day","Marriage","Anniversary")`.

I want to pass selected spinner value from one Activity to another and set that value in the spinner of different Activity.

I am able to pass the value of spinner using Intent, but don't know how to set that in my second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create same String array in the second Activity and pass which position was selected in the spinner from first activity using intent. Then you can use the following code in the second Activity to set Spinner value

```
spinner.setSelection(getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0););
```

Answer (score 0):

-------------CurrentActivity------

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);

Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putString("name", sp.getSelectedItem().toString());

i.putExtras(b);

startActivity(i);
```

-------------NextActivity------------------

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

String name = b.getString("name");

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity use SharedPreference when spinner item is selected

```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                int Position=position;//it will have selected item position
                SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                editor.putInt("Position", Position);
                editor.commit();
```

This would save your position in settings.
Now in your next activity make a function

```
    int getPos(String str)
    {
    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int Position=sp.getInt(str,0);
    return Position;
    }
```

And after setting adapter for spinner add this statement:

```
    Spinner.setSelection(getPos("Position"));
    //your code
```